# issue with java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Tags: java, android, listview, broadcastreceiver, indexoutofboundsexception

i need to delete the sms scheduled from `listview` when it has been sent...i get this error:`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0` when `broadcast receiver`try to send sms, but when i click button "scheduled" it is added to `list view`......now i show you my code!

Thanks in advance everybody!

i hope that you can help me!

PS: if i added this method:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                                long id) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item has been added into your list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                //  .show();
            dataSms.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

it works but i want that first item is deleted automatically after sms sent!

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int PERMS_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    TextView textViewTime;
    TimePicker timePicker;
    Button button;

    int hour;
    int minutee;
    //int hour;
    //int minute;


    final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;

    public String sPhone,sSms;
    public EditText etPhone,etSms;

    public Button bStart,bCancel,bTimeSelect,bPhone;
    ArrayList<Sms> dataSms;
    ListView listView;
    public static CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        dataSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(dataSms, getApplicationContext());

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        bStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bStart);
        //bCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
        bTimeSelect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bTime);
        bPhone = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bCPhone);





        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            /*  if (hasPermissions()) {
                    // our app has permissions.
                    scheduleAlarm(v);
                } else {
                    //our app doesn't have permissions, So i m requesting permissions.
                    requestPerms();
                }*/
                scheduleAlarm(v);

            }
        });

        bTimeSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"TimePicker");

            }
        });

        //};
        bPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://contacts");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uri);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });



    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

        //TimePicker timePicker;
        //int hour;
        //int minutee;

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            //Use the current time as the default values for the time picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            //Create and return a new instance of TimePickerDialog
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, hour, minute,
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }



        //onTimeSet() callback method
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){

            hour=hourOfDay;
            minutee=minute;






        }
    }



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void scheduleAlarm(View V) {
        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSms);
        String name = et1.getText().toString();
        String sms = et2.getText().toString();
        //adapter.add(new Sms(name, sms));




        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        //Long time= new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+24*60*60*1000;
        Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() + 10000;
        //Long time= System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;

        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putCharSequence("Number", name);
        bundle.putCharSequence("Message", sms);
        intentAlarm.putExtras(bundle);



        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutee);
        //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));


        Toast.makeText(this, "Messaggio programmato!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        adapter.add(new Sms(name, sms));








    }



}
```

BROADCAST RECEIVER:

```
  public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    private Intent intent;
    String value1 = null;
    String value2 = null;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> al;
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    ArrayList<Sms> dataSms;
    public static CustomAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        dataSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(dataSms, context);

        //dataSms.remove(0);
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(0));


        String phoneNumberReciver = "";

        String message = "blablabla";





        String name = intent.getStringExtra("Number");
        String sms = intent.getStringExtra("Message");

        /*String SPhone =i.getStringExtra("exPhone");
        String SSms = i.getStringExtra("exSmS");*/
        //android.telephony.SmsManager sms= SmsManager.getDefault();
        //sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumberReciver, null, message, null, null);
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(name, null, sms, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Messaggio inviato!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        dataSms.remove(0);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    /*    @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            liste.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }*/

//    public Intent getIntent() {
//        return intent;
//    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check before deleting! If you have nothing to delete

Comment: but in list view appear me sms scheduled...

Answer (score 2):

The error is in stacktrace :

```
dataSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
// ...
dataSms.remove(0);
```

You never add item in list, but you want to remove one

Comment: if i add this method @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item has been added into your list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) // .show(); dataSms.remove(position); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); } it works....but i must click on item to delete it.....

Answer (score 0):

There is no data in your ArrayList. That's why stack trace is saying size is 0. If the size is 0 then how are you removing element from ArrayList.

Remove this line `dataSms.remove(0);`

Comment: so, in main activity,   adapter.add(new Sms(name, sms)); doesn't work?

Comment: No. It will not work. Look, whenever you are adding item to the list then you must notify the adapter.

Comment: if i add this method @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item has been added into your list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) // .show(); dataSms.remove(position); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); } it works....but i must click on item to delete it.....

Comment: If you want to update the listView on sms sent. then create the method where you need to update listview  in MainActivity class. And pass sent sms position of listView to the AlarmReceiver and then call that method by passing sent sms position from AlarmReceiver class.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your ArrayList which you have declared. I think after declaring you have not added anything in your array list.

```
dataSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
```

I suggest you to go line by line debugging.
Before trying to remove value from your arrayList. Try to check if its size is zero or is it empty. If not then you can try with your next step.

```
dataSms.remove(0);
```

Please vote and mark if the solution is useful.

**Thanks!**

Comment: if i add this method  @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
         long id) {
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item has been added into your list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
     // .show();
    dataSms.remove(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   } it works....but i must click on item to delete it.....